# New Illustrator file with guide every 80cm

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have to design a roll-up banner, that's as wide as 4 roll-up banners and also exists of 4 roll-up banners that will be placed next to each other.

These banners should have one design that continues (think red carpet background with logo's, white beach background in photo studios), but I want to design it in one file and split it up afterwards.

This is why I am looking to create a new file with a vertical guide every 80 cm. Of course, this could be adapted for anyone and any measurement, but I'm looking for 80cm at this point.

I know I can just create a 320cm-wide file and create an 80cm block that I move after placing the guide, but I'm convinced there is some easier way I just never heard of.

Comment: Have you considered using Artboards for this?

Comment: Ah, there we go, that's useful! I have only recently made the move from Photoshop, so have no idea what functions can be found in Illustrator. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Artboards](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/artboard-overview.html) are a perfect fit for you as they can be aligned and reordered as you wish.